# How to sync Property in ObservableCollection in ViewModel and ListBox Item in View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I want sync string Dependency Property of UserControl's ViewModel and ListBox's Item in View.I tried to bind, but it didn't work.

I want to make todo manager like Trello.

The apps has nest structure.
MainWindow has 2 SampleContainerView s.
Each SampleContainerView has ListBox(ObservableCollection in ViewModel).
and the ListBox has SampleControls (This is UserControl which has TextBox).

Below is codes.

SampleControl.xaml

```
<Grid
    Background="Gray"
    >
    <TextBox
        Margin="10"
        Text="{Binding Title}"
        >
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

SampleVM.cs

```
public class SampleVM :DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Title",
                            typeof(string),
                            typeof(SampleVM));

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public SampleVM(string title="init")
    {
        SetValue(TitleProperty, title);
    }
}
```

SampleContainer.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding SampleList}"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.Row="0"
        >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:SampleControl></local:SampleControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button
        Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="10">
        add Sample...
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

SampleContainverVM.cs (omit DelegateCommand Implement here)

```
    public class SampleContainerVM : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SampleListProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("SampleList",
                        typeof(ObservableCollection<SampleVM>),
                        typeof(SampleContainerVM));

        public ObservableCollection<SampleVM> SampleList
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<SampleVM>)GetValue(SampleListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SampleListProperty, value); }
        }

        public DelegateCommand AddCommand { get; set; }

        public SampleContainerVM()
        {
            SetValue(SampleListProperty, new ObservableCollection<SampleVM>());
            AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(
                AddSample,
                () => { return true; });
        }

        private void AddSample()
        {
            SampleList.Add(new SampleVM());
        }
    }
```

`DataContext = new VM()` in every xaml.cs

Now I can add `SampleControl` to `ListBox` in `SampleContainer` by clicking button.

The problem is:
Instances(`Title Property`) in `SampleList` of `SampleContainer` don't change even when I change text in View.

Should I add any eventhandler?

Comment: Why do you use DependencyObject as base class of viewmodel? DO is pure UI class and it has nothing to do with viewmodels. The only thing you need to do for viewmodel is implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Besides that you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead of deriving from DependencyObject, you may want to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the TextBox's Text Binding in your SampleControl.

Comment: OK, I was mixed up. I thought Dependency Property and CLR Property with INotifyPropertyChanged was almost same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought too much about `DependencyProperty` and I should think simply.
I didn't need `DependencyProperty`.

I could achieve what I want as follows:

SampleVM.cs

```
public class SampleVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SampleVM(string title="init")
    {
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

SampleContainerVM.cs

```
public class SampleContainerVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<SampleVM> SampleList { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand AddCommand { get; set; }

    public SampleContainerVM()
    {
        SampleList = new ObservableCollection<SampleVM>();
        AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            AddSample,
            () => { return true; });
    }

    private void AddSample()
    {
        SampleList.Add(new SampleVM());
    }
}
```

SampleContainer.xaml(Delete Sample.xaml and write into `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.SampleContainer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding SampleList}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            Grid.Row="0"
            >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox
                        Margin="10"
                        Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     >
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button
            Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10">
            add Sample...
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```